# For loop in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, zsh, tcsh

I have a script which I need to run with many input combinations. Currently I'm doing it with a perl script but I want to learn how to do it in a shell.

I need to run `./script.pl a b`
for all combinations of a=1..100 and b =1..100

```
for ($a = 1; $a <100; $a++) {
    for ($b = 1; $b <100; $b++) {
      system "./script.pl $a $b";
        }
}
```

I'm currently using bash, but zsh or tcsh work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 choices of syntax in [bash for loops](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/).

```
for VARIABLE in 1 2 3 4 5 .. N
do
    commands
done
```

and

```
for (( EXP1; EXP2; EXP3 ))
do
    commands
done
```

The first is similar to java loops for navigating lists etc, while the second is the old school for loop.

You can rewrite your loops as either of these.

```
for b in {1..100}
do
   ./script $a $b
done
```

or

```
for ((b = 1; b <100; b++))
do
   ./script $a $b
done
```